# Have two javascipt arrays to combine into one object and add up values

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I want to combine the following two same-size arrays:

```
var depts = [ 'A', 'D', 'M', 'G', 'D', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'A' ];
var cnts  = [  3,   7,  15,   2,   9,   5,   12,  4,   8  ];
```

Into an object like this, note cnts are the totals for each depts:

```
{A: 15, D: 19, M: 15, G: 2, B: 5}
```

Normally I perform data manipulation prior to web site integration however I want begin performing it in JavaScript.  Some code that roughly mimics what I'm trying to do.

```
var obj = {};
for(var i = 0; i < depts.length; i++)
{
    console.log(depts[i], cnts[i]);
    obj[depts[i]] = cnts[i]; // <-  don't know how to increment assignment 
}
console.log(obj);
```

This code creates an object however does not sum cnts by depts:

```
{A: 8, D: 12, M: 15, G: 2, B: 5}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a check if the property exist and assign zero. Later add the value to it.

```js
var depts = ['A', 'D', 'M', 'G', 'D', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'A'],
    cnts = [3, 7, 15, 2, 9, 5, 12, 4, 8],
    obj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < depts.length; i++) {
    if (!obj[depts[i]]) obj[depts[i]] = 0; // use an initial value
    obj[depts[i]] += cnts[i];              // add value
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Interesting that you are not the one to post unreadable reduces. This time mine is the more elegant and Moritz's is completely overkill

Comment: very clear and understandable, thank you.  this works and something to build from.

Comment: @mplungjan: Interesting, because I almost always find Nina's answers the most readable ones around.  Maybe that's because I find `reduce` perfectly readable. :-)  I would be happy enough with Moritz's solution if we removed the `return` and replaced the unreadable `~~` with `|| 0`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet So you do not find this simpler and more elegant? `depts.forEach((dept,i) => obj[dept] = (obj[dept] || 0) + cnts[i])` even though it does not have a reduce?

Comment: No, I find mutation inherently more complex.  That's part of why I choose `reduce`, but also because `reduce` has some reasonable semantics, the same way `find`, `filter`, and `map` do.  `forEach` does not.  I'd be fine with `depts.reduce((res, dept, i) => ({...res, [dept]: (res[dept] || 0) + cnts[i]}), {})`

Comment: @ScottSauyet Ok, understood. I am more pragmatic. If it is ok to create the object outside the loop, then translating a for( i;test;inc) to a forEach makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: @mplungjan: Yes, it's a big difference.  I find for-loops, especially JS's C-style ones, pretty horrible.  I'm not sure if yours is more pragmatic or not, but we have very different styles.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
const depts = [ 'A', 'D', 'M', 'G', 'D', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'A' ];
const cnts  = [  3,   7,  15,   2,   9,   5,   12,  4,   8  ];
let obj = {};

// loop over the first array, if not already in obj, put a zero before adding
depts.forEach((dept,i) => obj[dept] = (obj[dept] || 0) + cnts[i])

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: thank you, this works too when loaded. For some reason DW6 complains about syntax on this line "depts.forEach((dept,i) => {".

Answer (score 0):

```js
var depts = [ 'A', 'D', 'M', 'G', 'D', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'A' ];
var cnts  = [  3,   7,  15,   2,   9,   5,   12,  4,   8  ];

const lkp = depts.reduce((lkp, cur, i) => {
    return {
        ...lkp,
        [cur]: ~~lkp[cur] + cnts[i]
    }
}, {})
console.log (lkp)
```

Comment: Ahh come on. That is impossible to read - especially for a noob. At least add some explanation

Comment: indeed :)    Just something I'll have to come back to when I got some mileage in js

Comment: I think it needs cleanup, yes.  But what it really needs is explanation.  Code-only answers are rarely useful. It could also possibly do with a note on the [potential performance problem](https://www.richsnapp.com/blog/2019/06-09-reduce-spread-anti-pattern) of the reduce-spread pattern.

Comment: @codeHacker I have been writing JS since 1996. The above is as close to awk one can get in JS ;)

Comment: @mplungjan: Come on, I'm sure we could get closer if we tried.  I've been training newbies for years, and their code rarely looks like this.  But I've also trained intermediate developer who *think* they are senior developers.  And a lot of their code is less readable than this!